# Replacing rows of a file with rows of another file

Tags: python, numpy

I have two point cloud files (Scene and Green) in .txt format. Scene point cloud usually contains more than 100000 lines and green one contains 20000 lines for example. These two files have equal lines for green points except the last number which is a label for each point.

**Scene:**

```
0.805309, -3.43696, 6.85463, 0, 0, 0, 5
0.811636, -3.42248, 6.82576, 0, 0, 0, 5
-1.00663, 0.0985967, 3.02769, 42, 134, 83, 5
-1.00182, 0.098547, 3.02617, 43, 133, 83, 5
-0.997052, 0.0985018, 3.02478, 41, 133, 82, 5
0.811636, -3.42248, 6.82576, 0, 0, 0, 5
```

**Green:**

```
-1.00663, 0.0985967, 3.02769, 42, 134, 83, 3
-1.00182, 0.098547, 3.02617, 43, 133, 83, 3
-0.997052, 0.0985018, 3.02478, 41, 133, 82, 3
```

I want to replace the whole line in Scene's green point with its equal line in Green file or only change the label number from 5 to 3 wherever the both lines are equal. The final result would be like this:
 **Scene:**

```
0.805309, -3.43696, 6.85463, 0, 0, 0, 5
0.811636, -3.42248, 6.82576, 0, 0, 0, 5
-1.00663, 0.0985967, 3.02769, 42, 134, 83, 3
-1.00182, 0.098547, 3.02617, 43, 133, 83, 3
-0.997052, 0.0985018, 3.02478, 41, 133, 82, 3
0.811636, -3.42248, 6.82576, 0, 0, 0, 5
```

I have written two types of code to do this, but both of them loads for significant amount of time which is not good at all, because of I have many files to modify.
First Code:

```
import os
import fileinput
def main(scene, others):

    for file in others:
        other = open(file, "r+")
        for line in other:
            line1 = line[:-3]
            f=scene
            for sceneLine in fileinput.input(f,inplace=True):
                new = sceneLine
                sceneLine1 = sceneLine[:-3]
                if sceneLine1 == line1:
                    print(sceneLine.replace(new, line), end='')
                else:
                    print(sceneLine.replace(line,line), end='')
            fileinput.close()


others = []
for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        if file.startswith("pointCloudScene9863Cl"):
            scene = file
        else:
            others.append(file)

main(scene,others)
```

**Second Code:**

```
import os
import fileinput
import numpy

def main(scene1, others):

    pointcloud = []
    scene1 = open(scene1,"r+")
    scene = []
    for each_point in scene1:
        scene.append(each_point)

    for file in others:
        other = open(file, "r+")
        for line in other:
            pointcloud = []
            line1 = line[:-3]
            for sceneLine in scene:
                sceneLine1 = sceneLine[:-3]
                if sceneLine1 == line1:
                    pointcloud.append(line)
                else:
                    pointcloud.append(sceneLine)
            scene = pointcloud

    with open('pointcloud.txt', 'w') as points:
        for item in scene:
            points.write("%s" % item)


others = []
for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        if file.startswith("pointCloudScene9863Cl"):
            scene = file
        else:
            others.append(file)

main(scene,others)
```

Both of these work perfectly with small number of points but when I use my orginal point cloud file, then it takes for more than 30 minutes or even more to finish the job. I actually see the problem in the FOR LOOP when I am basically using NESTED LOOPS, which means I will have 100000*20000 loops for changing the green points.

Is there an efficient way by using numpy arrays or any other methods?

Comment: I think that basically you'd be better off loading both file contents to arrays (100k and 20k lines is not *that much*), compare the arrays to create the desired output array, then save the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution which should be adequate, but before I go over that, a disclaimer: It will be impossible to find a proper solution without more information from you. We need context for this problem, and much more precise and detailed  information on the data format and what you are trying to do.

For example, comparing floats for equality doesn't feel great, and the manipulation of numbers in general always carries a certain risk in terms of precision, etc. Since these points seemingly come from the same place, it would be great if each one had some sort of unique ID that could be used to check for equality.

---

Like some of the other people here, my first reflex was to grab numpy and pandas. It was a mistake on my part, as this task does not involve much data manipulation or transformation at all.

Here, then, is the simplest implementation I can think of right now:

```
def point_parse(line):
    line_point = line.split(", ")
    line_point[0] = float(line_point[0])
    line_point[1] = float(line_point[1])
    line_point[2] = float(line_point[2])
    line_point[3] = int(line_point[3])
    line_point[4] = int(line_point[4])
    line_point[5] = int(line_point[5])
    line_point[6] = int(line_point[6])
    return tuple(line_point)

green_points_set: frozenset
black_points_set: frozenset

with open("../resources/Green_long.txt", "r") as green_file:
    green_points_set = frozenset((point_parse(line)[:-1] for line in green_file))

with open("../resources/Black_long.txt", "r") as black_file:
    black_points_set = frozenset((point_parse(line)[:-1] for line in black_file))

def set_point_label(point):
    point_comp = point[:-1]
    if point_comp in green_points_set:
        point_comp += (3,)
    elif point_comp in black_points_set:
        point_comp += (4,)
    else:
        point_comp = point
    return point_comp

with open("../resources/Scene_long.txt", "r") as scene_file:
    scene_points_new = (set_point_label(point_parse(line)) for line in scene_file)
    form_lines = ((f"{res_line[0]}, {res_line[1]}, {res_line[2]}, {res_line[3]}, "
               f"{res_line[4]}, {res_line[5]}, {res_line[6]}\n") for res_line in scene_points_new)

    with open("../out/Scene_out.txt", "w") as scene_out:
        scene_out.writelines(form_lines)
```

The code is quite straightforward. Sets are created for the green and black points, we test for membership, and change the label appropriately.

I created some training data for myself: a Scene with 1,000,000 points total, 125,000 green points, and 125,000 black points. Runtime was under 7 seconds (hopefully I haven't made any crucial mistakes!), memory use should be low.

Comment: I have used the "in" in my code as well and I should say it works far better than writing a loop and using "==" but it still takes some times to do the job. I will try your code soon and if the performance is that good I'll accept it as the solution, thanks.

Comment: I checked the code and it works smoothly and gives the result in couple of seconds even with 5 different label files. I think the trick was using a frozenset as you used it to create set with unique keys, I do understand your point for float numbers now. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Really elegant, using `frozensets`! However I still like `numba` ;-) Since you write about comparing floats, you still do that in your code, right? Did you check what happens if you just leave strings in the tuple?

Comment: @MrFuppes i'm sure that it could technically function, but it would probably be even worse than dealing with floats!

Comment: @Morti no problem, I'm glad to hear that it does the job! Sets are indeed the key here, since the only thing we care about is membership.

Comment: @Morti I forgot to mention in my previous comment that generators almost certainly play a big role here, sets aren't the only ones who deserve credit!

Comment: Thank You again to both of you @AlexanderCécile and MrFuppes for your guidance :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should ask yourself some essential questions about your data:

1. Is the order in the files preserved? I mean, do you have to search through entire file at all times, or after finding green point at some place you can skip comparisons on some part of the file?
2. 100000 records is not that much. Will it ever be, like, 1000 times more? Can you read entire file into the memory (Numpy array or DataFrame) once, so you can use your RAM and CPU cache, instead of reading from disk multiple times? Setting offset on recently found green point would make a viable option then.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, loading the file into the list is not same as loading the file into memory by using the numpy array? I mean, python list and numpy array are both load the data into the memory if I am not wrong.

Comment: I am specifically talking about
`for sceneLine in fileinput.input(f,inplace=True):`
or
`for sceneLine in scene:`
. Do you need all these iterations, or you can restrict it? Having your data in array or dataframe would enable you to know where you are in scenes by saving current index, and look only forward instead of looking at entire file.

Comment: well, in the second code I am loading the scene data into a list which did not help, I also changed the loading of green data but it did not help at all. I think I have to find a regexp to reduce the number of going through the second loop.

Answer (score 2):

A 'brute force' solution using `numba` jit compilation. Just for fun, better use the [`frozenset`-approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58297306/10197418). The most costly operation is the memory IO during `mod_arr[j,:] = mod[i,:]` it seems.

```py
import timeit
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

### numba njit-ed version of nested loops
@njit
def modify(arr, mod, tol=0.000000001):
    mod_arr = arr[:]
    mask = np.ones(arr.shape[0]).astype(np.bool_)
    idx = np.arange(0, arr.shape[0], 1)
    for i in range(mod.shape[0]):
        for j in idx[mask]:
            if np.absolute(np.sum(arr[j,:-1]-mod[i,:-1])) < tol:
                mod_arr[j,:] = mod[i,:]
                mask[j] = False
    return mod_arr

# "scene":
a = np.array([[0.805309, -3.43696, 6.85463, 0, 0, 0, 5],
              [0.811636, -3.42248, 6.82576, 0, 0, 0, 5],
              [-1.00663, 0.0985967, 3.02769, 42, 134, 83, 5],
              [-1.00182, 0.098547, 3.02617, 43, 133, 83, 5],
              [-0.997052, 0.0985018, 3.02478, 41, 133, 82, 5],
              [0.811636, -3.42248, 6.82576, 0, 0, 0, 5]])
# "green":
m = np.array([[-1.00663, 0.0985967, 3.02769, 42, 134, 83, 3],
              [-1.00182, 0.098547, 3.02617, 43, 133, 83, 3],
              [-0.997052, 0.0985018, 3.02478, 41, 133, 82, 3]])
# desired output:
mod_arr_test = np.array([[0.805309, -3.43696, 6.85463, 0, 0, 0, 5],
                         [0.811636, -3.42248, 6.82576, 0, 0, 0, 5],
                         [-1.00663, 0.0985967, 3.02769, 42, 134, 83, 3],
                         [-1.00182, 0.098547, 3.02617, 43, 133, 83, 3],
                         [-0.997052, 0.0985018, 3.02478, 41, 133, 82, 3],
                         [0.811636, -3.42248, 6.82576, 0, 0, 0, 5]])
# check:
mod_arr = modify(a, m)
print([np.isclose(np.sum(mod_arr[i] - l), 0.) for i, l in enumerate(mod_arr_test)])
# -->
[True, True, True, True, True, True]

# now let's make the arrays big...
a = np.tile(a, (17000, 1)) # a.shape is (102000, 7)
m = np.tile(m, (7000, 1)) # m.shape is (21000, 7)

### performance check:
%timeit modify(a, m)
# -->
2min 55s ± 4.07 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not familiar with some of the stuff that you did. but what if we can write it in a way that it can jump from the black points?  something like a RegExp that says there is no need to check the black points. I have other colors as well, so I only black points can be unchecked.

Comment: @Morti: well, the numba stuff only works with numeric data. So you would need to convert it first but that should be reasonably fast. String matching could be an option; I need to check.

Comment: It did not work for my large points, I stopped the program after about 45 minutes, my original scene point cloud contains about 460000 points and the green one is about 50000.

Comment: By "points" you mean lines in a file containing numeric information like the you showed in the question?

Comment: Yes, each line in the scene file contains the information of each point in the point cloud, X,Y,Z,R,G,B and its label.

Comment: another question to clarify ;-) - you only want to check color (RGB) and only want to change the label accordingly, meaning that position (XYZ) doesn't matter for the operation?

Comment: Yes, but I do not think that a color range works properly, because there might be some points that their RGB value are close to each other, in fact I tried to collect them in a way that they stay away from each other but I do not take the risk of writing a code for RGB value only, I mean the them point XYZ can be considered as a key but RGB itself is not a perfect key.